# Unable to set deployment-side credentials for AWS Amplify in order to access SSM Parameter Store with aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js

(I'm very new to AWS.)

I'm building a Next.js site and want to use API routes, and I need to use a secret key in order to fetch data from an external API in this route, so I decided to use AWS' Systems Manager -> Parameter Store to retrieve this secret key from, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to attain the credentials on the deployment-side.

I'm importing `aws-sdk` and retrieving the parameter like so:

```
    import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

    const ssm = new AWS.SSM();


    let secret;
    try {
        const param = await ssm.getParameter({
            Name: '/amplify/id/backend/name', // how i set it up as an example
            WithDecryption: true
        }).promise();

        if (!param || !param.Parameter || !param.Parameter.Value) {
            throw new Error('Parameter or value not found');
        }

        secret = param.Parameter.Value;

    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof Error) {
            return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Error fetching secret', details: e.message }), { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
        } else {
            return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred' }), { status: 500, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
        }    }
```

Before I can even retrieve the value, I'm getting this error when sending a request to this route:
`"Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"`

This is occuring on the deployment environment of AWS Amplify, and I was under the impression that `aws-sdk` would automatically attain the credentials from deployment due to GPT-4's walkthrough. I haven't really been able to find concrete explanation or documentation on this process, but assuming the credentials are checked with IAM, I placed the `AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess` permission onto the service role of this AWS Amplify app.

If that's incorrect, how do I set the credentials?